# CakePHP failing to save a certain column

Tags: cakephp, model, save

I'm trying to save a model like so:

```
$this->User->save(
    array(
        'User' => array(
            'id'                => $id,
            'persistent_hash'   => 'test',
            'name'              => 'test'
        )
    ), 
    false
);
```

The model saves the name column as 'test', but the persistent_hash column remains unchanged. (I triple checked the column to make sure it was spelled correctly)

Comment: are the attribute accessible ? I mean can you bulk assign those attributes ? atleast ROR works that way

Comment: have you defined a schema or are you relying the automatic wiring of cake?

Comment: What SQL statement is generated by Cake?

Comment: Turns out it was caching the model schema's still, thanks @JohnP

Comment: @Rob Please add the solution for this as an answer so it will help people with the same problem in future :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out my config was set to debug mode 0. When CakePHP is in production mode, it caches the database schemas.

If you make changes to the structures of any tables, Cake won't notice until you either change the debug mode or clear the schema caches.